# General proof for a Vector Space over F?

Tags: linear-algebra

I've been self-studying Sheldon Axlers Linear Algebra Done Right and in the beginning of the book he covers the definition of a Vector Space. In one of his sentences he says "With the usual operations of addition and scalar multiplication, $F^n$ is is a vector space over $F$ **as you should verify**". But I'm confused as to how you would verify something like this?

What I know currently is that for a set to be a Vector Space (formally) it must satisfy a set of rules; commutativity, associativity, have an additive identity, additive inverse, multiplicative inverse and distributive properties. Additionally for a Vector Space V to be over a field F is must satisfy scalar multiplication and vector addition. Would we prove the second then in this case? In the example with $F^{\infty}$ Axler provides he defines these then still asks us to verify that $F^{\infty}$ is a vector space over $F$ which confuses me more. I would like to understand this before moving on, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You define the operations; but the definition of the operations, in and of itself, does not *prove* that they satisfy the required properties. You must prove that they do.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin What properties have to be satisfied? The ones I listed? And what about in the case where no operations are defined? Do we assume they are?

Comment: "$V$ is a vector space" is just short "$V$ is a vector space over the field $F$". Just some times you omit the field since it is understood from the context. They are not two different concepts

Comment: For example, say I want to define a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ using the positive reals as vectors. I need to tell you how to do "vector addition" of these "vectors", and how to do scalar multiplication. I tell you: "to 'vector-add' to positive reals, you multiply them: $a\oplus b= ab$, where $\oplus$ is the vector addition I am defining, and the right hand side is the usual product. To 'scalar-multiply' a real number by a positive real, you take the exponent: $r\odot a = a^r$, where $\odot$ is the scalar multiplication I am defining."  (cont)

Comment: (cont) You then need to verify that these definitions satisfy the relevant properties to be a vector space.

Comment: There are a bunch of axioms for a vector space. They include: (i) vector addition must be an operation (sum of two vector is indeed a vector); (ii) vector addition must be commutative; (iii) vector addition must be associative; (iv) vector addition must have a zero vector; (v) vector addition must have additive inverses; (vi) the scalar product of a scalar and a vector must be a vector; etc. Depending on exactly how you write them, they could be anything from four to ten properties that must be checked.

Comment: I don't have Axler with me, so I don't remember how he details the conditions. But he details them explicitly, and so you must verify that the given set/operations satisfy these conditions. When no operations are given explicitly, this is usually because it is clear what they must be from context. In the case of $F^n$ (or $F^{\infty}$) the intended operations are "coordinatewise addition" and "coordinatewise scalar multiplication": $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\oplus (b_1,\ldots,b_n) = (a_1+b_1,\ldots,a_n+b_n)$, and $r\odot(a_1,\ldots,a_n) = (ra_1,\ldots,ra_n)$.

Comment: The properties you need to verify are clearly stated in definition 1.19 of your book.

Comment: I see. In the case of $F^{n}$ we would just use arbitrary elements of $F^{n}$ and $F$ to prove each axiom? Since we aren't given any operations of scalar multiplication or vector addition? I'm assuming by defining these operations in the case of $F^{\infty}$ it changes how we prove each axiom? For instance commutativity.

Comment: You ARE GIVEN addition and scalar multiplication in $F^n$. They are definitions 1.12 and 1.17 of the book.

Comment: You **are** given operations: coordinatewise operations. How you prove each axiom depends on the set and operations defined. “Use arbitrary elements”... you are trying to prove that something holds for **all** choices of vectors (all axioms in the vector space start with “for all `blah`, `something happens`). This can never be done by doing specific calculations with specific objects, unless you can do it one-by-one with every possible choice of objects.

Comment: Also, example 1.22 DOES give the definitions of addition and scalar multiplication for $F^\infty$

Comment: Damn, I completely forgot about 1.12 and 1.17. I understand a lot better now thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

If you do linear algebra really right, you define a vector space with a *single* axiom as

> an abelian group on which a field acts.

The first part (abelian group - or in your terms: commutativity, associativity, have an additive identity, additive inverse) holds for $F^n$ (as well as for $F^\infty$) by defining the addition in an obvious manner, namely componentwise.

The second part, (the field action - or in your terms: distributive properties and multiplicative inverse  [though I'd prefer that $1\in F$ acts as identity]) also follows by defining the scalar multiplication in the obvious manner, i.e., component-wise.

You may also notice that $F^n$ and $F^\infty$ can be viewed as the set $F^X$ of all maps from a certain set $X$ to $F$ (e.g., take $X=\{1,\ldots,n\}$ to obtain $F^n$). In this view, component-wise addition/multiplication just means point-wise addition/multiplication, i.e., $f+g$ is the map $X\to F$ given by $(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)$ and $a\cdot f$ is the map $X\to F$ given by $(a\cdot f)(x)=a\cdot f(x)$. The desired laws then immediately follow from their validity for addition and multiplication in $F$ itself, i.e., because $F$ is a field.

Comment: The OP is struggling with the fact that $F^n$ is a vector space and you talk about an action of a field over an abelian group and give an more abstract definition of $F^n$? Really?